# SIP.js - Require rtcpMuxPolicy

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, asterisk, sip

I'm using SIP.js library for SIP phone, working on Chrome. After Chrome 57 my phone doesn't work. I can call a number but voice is unavailable or receive a call but phone isn't responding. I get this error on browser console:

> DOMException: Failed to set remote offer sdp: Session error code:
>   ERROR_CONTENT.
>   Session error description: rtcpMuxPolicy is 'require',
>   but media description does not contain 'a=rtcp-mux'..

I'm using `Chrome M57` and `SIP.js` 0.73. I updated `SIP.js` to 0.77 but the problem is there.

I look at google group and github. The problem is with `Chrome`. We use `asterisk`. What can I do for this problem?

Comment: Please post what you have tried and why that didn't work, that will make it much easier to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Google Chrome 57 introduced a new WebRTC requirement (RTCP multiplexing). Previously it was optional. You can install an older version of Chrome or update Asterisk, this new feature is requirement has already been met (https://issues.asterisk.org/jira/browse/ASTERISK-26732).

Read more: https://nimblea.pe/monkey-business/2017/01/19/webrtc-asterisk-and-chrome-57/

Answer (score -1):

After you have updated your sip version to 0.7.7+ then you need to set the **rtcpMuxPolicy** parameter to **"negotiate"** in **UA.prototype.loadConfig**:

```js
UA.prototype.loadConfig = function(configuration) {
  var parameter, value, checked_value, hostportParams, registrarServer,
    settings = {
      ...  
  
      rtcpMuxPolicy: 'negotiate',
      
      ...
      };
};
```

This should fix your problem.

> rtcpMuxPolicy
>
> String that overrides the default Multiplexing RTP (rtp-mux) mode used
>   for the peer connection. Setting this to “negotiate” may allow
>   endpoints that do not support rtp-mux to work with SIP.js. If not
>   specified, the browser’s default policy is used.
>
> Version: 0.7.7+
>
> rtcpMuxPolicy: "negotiate"

Comment: Your answer may be correct, but link-only answers are not really valuable in a long term (as the link may become invalid). Please quote the relevant parts of the content from the external link to your answer here.